# Mixing Angular Html5Mode and the default hash

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know if it's possible to use both html5Mode and the default hash ("#") behavior on the same site.

My site let users access documents this way:

http://127.0.0.1/#/20150730/123

And I want to change this to

http://127.0.0.1/20150730/123

I want to still allow users to access using /#/..., because some of them have those documents bookmarked. But the html5Mode is more natural (at least for me) and I want to set it as the default mode.

How can I do this?.

Comment: the hash is always functional, even if not shown, for support of browsers without HTML5 Push State support.

Comment: ahhh ...did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to retain the the default hash ('#') behaviour after enabling html5Mode, requests that include the hash will just continue to work.

This is because in older browsers that do not support html5Mode, Angular will automatically fall back to using the hash ('#') url style.

[From the docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> If the HTML5 History API is not supported by a browser, the $location
>   service will fall back to using the hashbang URLs automatically. This
>   frees you from having to worry about whether the browser displaying
>   your app supports the history API or not; the $location service
>   transparently uses the best available option.

Comment: Great answer. Now I'll have to figure out how to configure my server to handle /20150730/123, but that's another story.